# Which of words make up a predicator in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> They would make me feel alive.

Is 'would make feel' is a predicator here? Why?

Comment: From [Linguistics.SE,](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/predicate-vs-predicator) ***Predicator** means "(In systemic grammar) a verb phrase considered as a constituent of clause structure, along with subject, object, and adjunct." **Predicate** means "The part of a sentence or clause containing a verb and stating something about the subject (e.g. went home in John went home)."* Are those the definitions you have in mind?

Comment: ***BUT...*** [*The use of this terminology **varies tremendously** depending of the theory of **semantics, syntax, and grammar** that one adopts.*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/11998/282) I suspect that knowing whether or not some specific technical term is "correct" isn't actually what you're after. What is it you ***really*** want to know, and why?

Comment: I prefer to understand correctness of used predicator first.

Comment: Your cited example text is perfectly valid English, if that's what you mean. I neither know nor care about the relevant linguistic / grammatical terminology.